# Validating username through Express

Tags: mongodb, angularjs, express

I have a schema like this

```
{
     "_id": ObjectId("52eb4b3f2ae235294899259d"),
     "username": "david",
     "email": "test@gmail.com",
     "practice": [{
         "name": "test1",
         "role": "superadmin",
         "status": "1"
     }, {
         "name": "test2",
         "role": "admin",
         "status": "1"
     }, {
         "name": "test3",
         "role": "admin",
         "status": "0"
     }]
}
```

In MongoDB, how can I validate if `username='david'` for `practice.name = 'test2'` and status='1' for test2 is present through Express.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) to match multiple fields in the same `practice` array element:

```
collection.findOne(
    {username: 'david', practice: {$elemMatch: {name: 'test2', status: '1'}}},
    function (err, user) { ... }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$and` operator for this. You can write the function to check like this.

```
    SchemaName.find({ $and: [ {username: "david"}, {'practice.name': 'test2'} ] }, 
                    function (err, found) {
                        if(err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log(found);
                        }
    })
```

Comment: function(req, email, password, done) {
      User.findOne({
        $and: [ {username: req.body.email }, {'practice.name': req.body.pname } ]     
      }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: 'This username/practicename is not registered.'
          });
        } after passing pname='test1' , 'username' = 'david' im getting This username/practicename is not registered.